# Two levels of items in an array list in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have an array list of items:

```
  items = [
    {id: '1', title: 'item 1'},
    {id: '2', title: 'item 2'},
  ]
```

I want to add categories to this list and filter based on that, for example

```
-items
-- cat1
--- item 1
--- item 2
-- cat2
--- item 1
--- item 2
-- cat3
--- item 1
--- item 2
```

Also, how would I change the ngFor code to select the cat

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="clicked($event, item)">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>



  clicked (event, item){
    console.log(item.title);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add categories, then your `items` array would look like this:

```
this.items = [
  { 
    id: 1, 
    title: 'Category 1', 
    items : [ 
              {id: 1, title: 'item 1'},
              {id: 2, title: 'item 2'} 
            ]
  },
  { 
    id: 2, 
    title: 'Category 2', 
    items : [ 
              {id: 3, title: 'item 3'},
              {id: 4, title: 'item 4'} 
            ]
  },
  { 
    id: 3, 
    title: 'Category 3', 
    items : [ 
              {id: 5, title: 'item 5'},
              {id: 6, title: 'item 6'} 
            ]
  }
];
```

And you can use two nested `*ngFor` to print the `items` array like this:

```
  <ion-list  no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="clicked($event, item)">
      Title: {{ item.title }} - Id: {{ item.id }}
      <p *ngFor="let subitem of item.items" no-lines>
        <span>Title: {{ subitem.title }} - Id: {{ subitem.id }}</span>
      </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Please find the full code in this [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UPYFmw?p=preview).

---

**UPDATE:**

> On opening the page how would I filter which category is shown? So,
>   I'd push to the items page and only want to show's the items only for
>   that category.

That could be easily achieved by using a [custom Pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html). I've updated the plunker so now the view looks like this:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <button (click)="showCategory(1)">Show Cat 1</button>
      <button (click)="showCategory(2)">Show Cat 2</button>
      <button (click)="showCategory(3)">Show Cat 3</button>
      <button (click)="showCategory(-1)">Show All</button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list  no-lines>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (items | categoryFilter:selectedCategoryId)" (click)="clicked($event, item)" >
      Title: {{ item.title }} - Id: {{ item.id }}
      <p *ngFor="let subitem of item.items" no-lines>
        <span>Title: {{ subitem.title }} - Id: {{ subitem.id }}</span>
      </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

The buttons in the first `<ion-item></ion-item>`will allow us to select which category we want to show (by using a new property in the typescript code `private selectedCategoryId : number;`, but all the magic is being done by this line of code

```
*ngFor="let item of (items | categoryFilter:selectedCategoryId)"
```

There we use a custom pipe to only include in the loop those categories whose `id` matches the `selectedCategoryId`. You can see that in the `CategoryFilter` code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'categoryFilter' })
export class CategoryFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], selectedId: number): any {
        if(selectedId === -1)
          return items;
        return items.filter(item => item.id === selectedId);
    }
}
```

I don't know what you want to accomplish, but if you don't want to show the buttons, you could just set the `selectedCategoryId` in the `constructor` of the page. Again, you can find that code in [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UPYFmw?p=preview).

Comment: On opening the page how would I filter which category is shown? So, I'd push to the items page and only want to show's the items only for that category

    <button (click)="items(cat1)">
    <div class="card-title">category 1</div>
    </button>

     <button (click)="items(cat2)">
    <div class="card-title">category 2</div>
    </button>

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself very well. I want to have those buttons you added on a separate page and you click them and it goes to the items page and only shows the category the user clicked.

Comment: In that case you could create a `Service` with the `items` array and a method like `getItemsByCategory(categoryId: number): any[] { ... }` and then when you press the button, just send the `categoryId` as a parameter in the `push`. Then in the constructor of the new page, get that parameter and call the service to get the items. You won't need the `Pipe` in that scenario.